# what is the difference between ServerResponse and http.IncomingMessage?

Tags: node.js

what is the difference between ServerResponse and http.IncomingMessage? I'm new in Node,and I'm really confused about these two object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `http.IncomingMessage` object represents the request information from the client received by the server. [See this link for the Node API docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage). So, this object contains things like the headers, the method (GET, POST, etc...), the URL requested, etc... It implements the `ReadableStream` interface -- which means you can read data from it using a stream -- and has several events, methods and properties. (too many to list here...)

The `ServerResponse` object represents the http server's response to the client. [See this link for the Node API docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse). With this object, you can set the headers that will be sent to the client, the status code and status message of the response, as well as any data to be returned. It implements the `WritableStream` interface -- which means you can write to it using a stream -- and also has several events, methods, and properties.

In many server side programs you'll see something like:

```
function foobar(req, res) {

}
```

The `req` variable holds the `http.IncomingMessage` object -- it's short for `request`. The `res` variable holds the `ServerResponse` object -- it's short for `response`.

Please see the documentation links for a full explanation of both objects.

Hope this helps!

Comment: yes,that really helps. But got another question, I use the npm request module to send my request,and the document said that **in the Request emits a "response" event when a response is received. The response argument will be an instance of http.IncomingMessage.** so ,the response  can also be a http.IncomingMessage?

Comment: Yes. In that case, your code is the client and you are sending a request to / receiving a response from the server. You can also see the http.ClientRequest object: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest.

Answer (score 1):

`req` is an IncomingMessage object and `res` is a ServerResponse object.

So check for unique properties on each, for example if the particular object has a writeHead() function, then it's the response object.

You may also be able to use instanceof to check: res instanceof http.ServerResponse.

Comment: do you understand difference between both